# Rename columns using values from separate dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble which has column names containing spaces & special characters which make it a hassle to work with. I want to change these column names to easier to use names while I'm working with the data, and then change them back to the original names at the end for display. Ideally, I want to be able to do this as part of a pipe, however I haven't figured out how to do it with `rename_with()`.

Sample data:

```
df <- tibble(oldname1 = seq(1:10),
             oldname2 = letters[seq(1:10)],
             oldname3 = LETTERS[seq(1:10)])


cols_lookup <- tibble(old_names = c("oldname4", "oldname2", "oldname1"), 
                      new_names = c("newname4", "newname2", "newname1"))
```

Desired output:

```
> head(df_renamed)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  newname1 newname2 oldname3
     <int> <chr>    <chr>   
1        1 a        A       
2        2 b        B       
3        3 c        C       
4        4 d        D       
5        5 e        E       
6        6 f        F
```

Some columns are removed & reordered during this work so when converting them back there will be entries in the `cols_lookup` table which are no longer in `df`. There are also new columns created in `df` which I want to remain named the same.

I am aware there are similar questions which have already been asked, however the answers either don't work well with tibbles or in a pipe (eg. those using `match()`), or don't work if the columns aren't all present in the same order in both tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `rename_at`.  From the master lookup table, `filter` the rows where the `names` of dataset have a match (`filtered_lookup)`, then use that in `rename_at` where we specify the 'old_names' in `vars` and replace with the 'new_names'

```
library(dplyr)
filtered_lookup <- cols_lookup %>% 
     filter(old_names %in% names(df)) 
df %>% 
  rename_at(vars(filtered_lookup$old_names), ~ filtered_lookup$new_names)
```

---

Or using `rename_with`, use the same logic

```
df %>%
  rename_with(.fn = ~filtered_lookup$new_names, .cols = filtered_lookup$old_names)
```

---

Or another option is `rename` with splicing (`!!!`) from a named vector

```
library(tibble)
df %>% 
     rename(!!! deframe(filtered_lookup[2:1]))
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'd rather avoid making a separate `filtered_lookup` table, and have all steps contained within the pipe.  A pipe within a pipe with your method works but it's a bit ugly!

`df %>% rename(!!! deframe((cols_lookup %>% filter(old_names %in% names(df)))[2:1]))`

As an aside, `rename_at` has been superseded with `rename_with`

Comment: @stiba for `rename` to work, it needs all the intersecting columns.  If there are names that are not there, it would fail

Comment: @stlba you canuse `rename_with` as well, only thing is that the arguments are reversed

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rename_` with `setnames`

```r
cols_lookup <- tibble(old_names = c("oldname3", "oldname2", "oldname1"), 
                      new_names = c("newname3", "newname2", "newname1"))
df
rename_(df, .dots=setNames(cols_lookup$old_names, cols_lookup$new_names))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   newname1 newname2 newname3
      <int> <chr>    <chr>   
 1        1 a        A       
 2        2 b        B       
 3        3 c        C       
 4        4 d        D       
 5        5 e        E       
 6        6 f        F       
 7        7 g        G       
 8        8 h        H       
 9        9 i        I       
10       10 j        J
```

Comment: That doesn't work with my example data, there is no oldname3/newname3 in my data. `rename_()` is also deprecated so I'd rather avoid it.