# Matching old and new column names in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rename, tidyr

I want to change column names using matched old and new column IDs. For example, using the iris dataset

```
data("iris")

head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa

oldID = colnames(iris)
newID = c("spl.lgth", "spl.wdth", "ptl.lgth", "ptl.wdth", "spp")
colnamechange = data.frame(oldID, newID)
```

I want to replace the column names regardless of order, using the `rename()` syntax of `newname = oldname`. Something like

```
rename(colnames(iris) = colnamechange)

head(iris)
     spl.lngth    spl.wdth    ptl.lngth    ptl.wdth     spp
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

I'm working with an ecological dataset that has hundreds of columns. I don't want to rely on those columns staying in the same order when I rename them and renaming them by hand is a big task.

Comment: Are you looking for `names(iris) <- newID` ?

Comment: It might help to provide some more detail or a more realistic example. In the example you give, ordering is not an issue. As @AllanCameron says, you can simply supply the new names as a vector and the order will match up with the old names automatically, because that's how you specified the columns in `colnamechange`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? A little dated, but the `rename_with` answer works using `colnamechange` https://stackoverflow.com/a/63287336/12400385

Comment: @nniloc That's exactly the solution I was looking for, thank you!